# Add a task to database in laravel then redirect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, task, laravel-5.5

I am making a simple task app in laravel to cement the basics into my head. I have a page set-up with a form to make a task then submit it to the database, then redirect back to the home page. when I click submit it gives me this screen:

The page has expired due to inactivity. 
Please refresh and try again.

my have the project on GitHub here: https://github.com/fullstackfox16/laravel-task

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that you forgot to add csrf_token field to your form.

```
<form method="POST" action="/posts">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"> <!-- THIS LINE --> 
  <div class="field">
    <label class="label">Task</label>
    <div class="control">
      <textarea class="textarea" placeholder="Textarea" name="body"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="field is-grouped">
    <div class="control">
      <button class="button is-primary">Add Task</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

And if the problem persists, clean your browser cache and try again.

Comment: Thank you! now it is giving me this error: "Class 'Post' not found". my code in the controller is: public function store()
    {
     $post = new \Post;

     $post->body = request('body');

     $post->save();

     return redirect('/');
    }

Comment: @L.Fox Where did you put your post model? I didn't find that.

Comment: Yes I have done some research since then and I was not using a post model! Laravel Newbie!!! Thank you for the help! I think I have everything figured out!

Comment: @L.Fox Good. If you want to learn Laravel by practice, there is a great book http://www.easylaravelbook.com/. Do not forget to Accept the answer and Vote Up. :)

Comment: Ok thank you for that book recommendation I will definitely check it out! I'm new to this site, what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

Can you more specific in your question. In general when using HTML form you can use redirect back after your request is handle with message bag to show a message feedback to your user, if you have white screen or something else abnormal  make sure you don't have error syntax

Comment: I'm pretty new to Laravel so I'm not sure if I have the code written correctly. Maybe you could look at my code to see if I did it properly? What I want to happen is this: I want to type in a new task then click submit and have the task save to the database, in the mean time I want I to redirect to the home page which I think I figured out.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can work this out:

One, is adding the `csrf_field()` in your form. nice and easy.

Or

you can omit that route form the `VerifyCsrfToken` middlaware.

```
app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php

 protected $except = [
        'your/route'
    ];
```

Comment: ok when I add the csrf_field() it shows up on the site in plain text. am I adding it wrong? I am using blade to add it

Comment: Ok I got it! I was forgetting the braces at the end of the csrf_field